# Python 3. Заполнение атрибутов класса словарем с пользовательским вводом

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть класс для хранения данных:

```
class SomeClass():
    def __init__(self, dict):
        self.__dict__.update(dict)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.__dict__)
```

Заполняется данными, он следующим образом:

```
some_variable = SomeClass({k: str(input("set the field {}: ".format(k)))
                           for k in ('name', 'phone', 'request_date')})
```

Необходимые задачи этот код решает, а именно:

- Считывание пользовательского ввода
- Динамическое создание полей класса на основе некого заранее подготовленного списка/кортежа

  Но является ли все это приемлемым кодом, либо это плохая практики и делать так ни в коем случае не стоит?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728243/is-self-dict-updatekwargs-good-or-poor-style

Comment: Чем вам не угодило просто использование словаря? Зачем вам понадобился класс?

Comment: Со словарем все замечательно, изначально все реализовано было именно со словарем. Решил реализовать с помощью классов для дальнейшей записи информации в БД посредством SQLAlchemy.

Comment: По средствам - проблема